# Load/Run JavaScript on demand, under localhost (no web server) and server environment

Tags: javascript, html

A html page contains multiple `divs`. These divs have one button in it and some sample text.

The content of div are `formatted` (simple bold, color, size etc) via script.

**Issue:** 
The content of div should get formatted only when user clicks button, and since div content is editable, formatting should get applied to updated text/content, after click.

**Tried:**
Adding and removing script tag via JavaScript.

Basic template I have now:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_library.js" async></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="format_call()">
<div id="page1" contentEditable='true'>
Bold Text. Italic text. Color Text.
</div>
</div>


<div>
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="format_call()">
<div id="page2" contentEditable='true'>
Bold Text. Italic text. Color Text.
</div>
</div>

</body>
<script>
function format_call() {
    var tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.type = "text/javascript";
    tag.src = "path_to_library.js";
    //document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);
    document.head.appendChild(tag).parentNode.removeChild(tag);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

**Note:**
No JQuery based solutions.

Comment: Is there a reson you aren't formatting the divs with CSS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: @bobjoe Yes, the formatting is just first part, later on script will performing some parsing and text transformation operations.